# c# asp net mvc5 - ¿Cómo ver que campo da problemas?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo un **controlador**, para editar un registro existente, con este código:

```
        [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "idCliente,tiendaCliente,id,tiendaVenta,fechaFactura"+
        "fechaEntregado,estadoPresupuesto")] Ventas ventas)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(ventas).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(ventas);
    }
```

El error se produce al intentar guardar, en **db.SaveChange()**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Éste es el **modelo**:

```
namespace testweb.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Ventas
    {
        public Ventas()
        {
            this.Caja = new HashSet<Caja>();
            this.Montajes = new HashSet<Montajes>();
            this.VentasLinias = new HashSet<VentasLinias>();
        }

        public int idCliente { get; set; }
        public byte tiendaCliente { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public byte tiendaVenta { get; set; }
        public string observaciones { get; set; }
        public decimal total { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> numeroFactura { get; set; }

        public System.DateTime fecha { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime fechaSistema { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Caja> Caja { get; set; }
        public virtual Clientes Clientes { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Montajes> Montajes { get; set; }
        public virtual Usuarios Usuarios { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<VentasLinias> VentasLinias { get; set; }
    }
}
```

He intentado debugar, buscando por todas las propiedades, pero no localizo el problema.
Gracias.

Comment: Intenta cambiar el tipo de dato de tu campo _fechaFactura_ y _fechaEntregado_ a _string_ en tu modelo , seguro está como _DateTime_ , _Aunque pueden haber mejores soluciones_

Comment: agrega tu modelo por favor :D

Comment: Acabo de añadir el modelo. Gracias

Comment: Tu modelo es generado por EF (Entity Framework)?

Comment: yo agregaria, cambiaste el modelo o la bd sin haber tocado su contraparte?

Answer (score 0):

El rango de valores de un DateTime en C# es diferente que el de SQL. Por lo que necesitas validar que el valor de tus campos fecha y fechaSistema correspondan al rango de valor de SQL.

Lo puedes logar con algo así como:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "idCliente,tiendaCliente,id,tiendaVenta,fechaFactura"+
    "fechaEntregado,estadoPresupuesto")] Ventas ventas)
    {
        if (ventas.fecha < System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.MinValue.Value)
        {
            //Handle error like
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(ventas).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(ventas);
    }
```